# What lens will fit a Canon 10D?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount

I got a Canon 10D from a friend, the camera doesn't have any lens so I've been trying to find lens for it online.

The problem is that I'm no expert in photography, and very unsure of what lens would fit this camera.

After looking around it seems like the camera needs EF lenses, but does it mean that every lens I find online that claim to be EF will fit it? or should I also look into sizes etc'?

What I'd also like to ask is whether it is possible to purchase an adapter for EF-S lenses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you need an EF lens, all EF lenses are compatible with all EF mount cameras.

You can't get an adapter for EF-S lenses because EF-S lenses go deeper into the camera and would hit the mirror of an EF camera body.

Comment: All EF-S lenses do not extend into the body, only some of them do. Mostly the wider angle ones. In the case of the Canon EOS 10D, it has an APS-C sized sensor and mirror and there should be no clearance problem with any EF-S lenses. The reason it is not officially "EF-S compatible" is that it was introduced prior to the EF-S line of lenses. You could probably remove the extra tab on the EF-S lens flange and use them without any issue with the 10D.

Comment: @MichaelClark you are suggesting it's a good idea to modify lenses in order to use them on a 10 years old digital camera body? even cheap EF-S lenses (except for 2nd hand 18-55) should be worth so much more than the body to make this modification financially unwise.

Comment: I made no judgement regarding whether it is a good idea or not, I merely theorized it was possible before finding examples of others who have done it. Most have done so with the 18-55 variants but at least one also with an EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5. With the metal mount lenses it is a very easy modification to remove a single plastic tab. It is actually more difficult and involved to modify the plastic mount on the original 18-55mm lenses.

Comment: And the second hand EF-S 18-55 lenses is what I would first look for if I were looking for something on the cheap for my cheap 10D. Beyond that, any modified lens would still work on any EF-S compatible body, just as an EF mount lens does.

Comment: A lot of good EF lenses are available.   Some relatively cheap too.  Don't consider modifying anything - if you find you like photography you will most likely buy a new camera house "soonish" and then it is nice that things still work as intended.    For starting a used 50 mm f/1.8 might be fun and relatively cheap :)

Answer (score 6):

The Canon 10D is designed to take any EF lens that Canon manufactures. Although it has an APS-C sized sensor and mirror, it was designed before Canon introduced the EF-S lens line.

Because it has the smaller image sensor, some third party lenses made only for APS-C cameras will work. For instance, the Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8 Di II will mount on any Canon EF body without demonstrating any clearance problems, even though the light circle it casts is not large enough to completely cover a 36X24 full frame sensor. In theory it is probably possible to modify the tab on EF-S lenses and use them on the 10D. There should be no clearance issues since the sensor and mirror are the same size as those in the subsequent 20D that can use EF-S lenses. In fact, Bob Atkins [did just that](http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/tutorials/efs-10d.html). So did [this guy](http://www.flickr.com/groups/canondslr/discuss/72157604422834954/). [This one](http://www.istockphoto.com/forum_messages.php?threadid=14325) used an EF 17-55mm f/2.8 IS.

Comment: what about the lens electronics? I remember there were in the past (and maybe still, haven't bought a new lens or camera in some years) a lot of episodes with 3rd party lenses not working with specific (usually newer I think) bodies without getting their control chips replaced.

Comment: Any third party lens made after the 10D should work. The 10D was released in early 2003. I successfully mounted and used the Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8 Di II on my 5D2. Of course there was extreme vignetting, but everything functioned properly and there were no clearance issues. The Tamron was introduced in early 2006, the 5D2 in late 2008.

Comment: The whole lens modification bit just muddies the waters.

Comment: Many of the third party lenses don't even need modification. They're basically lenses throwing an EF-S sized light circle with an EF mount.